# Need to convert a Sencha Touch + NodeJs + MongoDB app to Native apps

Tags: ios, extjs, sencha-touch, native, hybrid-mobile-app

Based on our user feedback, we would like to convert our Hybrid app built using Sencha Touch on Node JS & MongoDb to pure Native apps for both IOS and Android. Having built a lot of logic and data, what are our most optimal choices to keep as much of backend REST API code as possible and save on time, cost and effort.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your API endpoints are properly detached from the rest of the app, you will only have to rewrite the native logic for iOS and Android. If everything is intertwined then the first thing you need to do is separate the API calls into their own self sustained application.

Answer (score 1):

**Before discarding ST be sure you are getting the best performance possible:**

1.- build for production with sencha CMD.

2.- be sure you are not over-nesting components (more than needed).

3.- use container when possible instead of panels

4.- if possible avoid nested lists

5.- be sure you are not creating components over and over again when you can show / hide them.

6.- be aware of memory leaks.

7.- Smart DOM query e.g this.down('myPanel') instead of Ext.ComponentQuery.query('myPanel')

8.- Make the UI to respond while server side is processing stuff (use of masks and stuff like that)

I'm sure there are more things you can do to get the best out of the framework, research them.

I believe Sencha Touch is awesome, look for some of the demos they have and if the performance of those apps are like the one you have and you still don't like it, then ok move to native.

In good ST apps users aren't able to tell if it's hybrid or native.

**UPDATE 
BTW you are using something like Cordova or PhoneGap to package it right ?**